# Rails Action Mailer not showing body with layout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, layout, actionmailer

I've recently set up a few mailers and I am trying to get a layout across all mailers.
This has been done by creating an `ApplicationMailer.rb` which contains this:

```
class Application < ActionMailer::Base
    layout 'mailer'
end
```

I have a `mailer.html.erb` file in `app/views/layouts` and the `mailer.text.erb` in the same place.

mailer.html.erb:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<HTML lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <%= yield %>
    <hr>
    <footer>
        Message sent from "xxx"
    </footer>
</html>
```

This is working well with our PasswordMailer:

```
class PasswordMailer < ApplicationMailer
    def password_changed(user)
        @user = user
        mail(:to => user.email, :subject => t('mailer.email_topic_password_changed'))
    end
end
```

But this layout is not working with my other mailer:

```
class SystemImportMailer < ApplicationMailer
  def notify_email(params)
    mail(to: params[:email],
         subject: "#{t('admin.import_export.import_file')}"
         body: params[:body])
  end
end
```

This mailer just shows the body as usual, without including the message in the layout.
If I remove the `body: params[:body])` line, it shows the layout message. I'm not sure why this would be the case.

Thanks

EDIT:
I also have this Mailer using a different technique of adding a body.

```
class ScheduleMailer < ApplicationMailer
  def send_start_email(params)
    mail(to: params[:to], subject: I18n.t('schedule.start_subject')) do |format|
      format.text do
        render :text => I18n.t('schedule.start_message', type: params[:type], key: params[:key], company: params[:company]
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, That will not work. When you say:

```rb
mail(to: params[:email],
         subject: "#{t('admin.import_export.import_file')}"
         body: params[:body])
```

The `body` parameter will replace all of your `mailer` layout template and thus your email content will only have `params[:body]` content in it. If you don't pass `body` paramater(like in `password_mailer`) it will check for views in `app/views/password` mailer folder and render that view to email.

So instead of using the `body` parameter to `mail`, you can create an instance variable and access that inside the `notify_email.html.erb` or `notify_email.text.erb` file.

So in your mailer file:

```rb
class SystemImportMailer < ApplicationMailer
  def notify_email(params)
    # create this variable
    @body_content = params[:body]
    mail(to: params[:email],
         subject: "#{t('admin.import_export.import_file')}")
  end
end
```

Then in your `notify_email.html.erb` or `notify_email.text.erb`:

```
<p><%= @body_content %></p>
```

**EDIT:**
You didn't mention your usecase, but still your complicating things when rails makes this easy.

1. If you want to use instance var only for `text` version of mail then you can create `@text_only_body = params[:body]`, then include this `@text_only_body` in your `send_start_email.text.erb`. Dont include it in your `.html.erb` file Ex:

   ```rb
   # Mailer
   def send_start_email(params)
     @text_only_body = params[:body]
     mail(to: params[:to], subject: I18n.t('schedule.start_subject'))
   end

   # send_start_email.text.erb
   Hello, <%= text_only_body %>
   ```
2. If you only want to send text emails, you don't want to send HTML emails, then do something this:

   ```rb
   def send_start_email(params)
     @text_only_body = params[:body]
     mail(to: params[:to], subject: I18n.t('schedule.start_subject')) do |format|
       format.text
     end
   end
   ```

Comment: Thank you! That's working great. 
Would you be able to have a look at the other example I've added to my question? 
I'm unsure how I would get this data into the layout like for the ```SystemImportMailer```